# Vds meaning in characteristic curve of a MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, datasheet, pmos, fet

[image]

As I was wrapping up my design (which didn't include MOSFETs as switches tho, yet), I've realized I wanted to make it crystal clear for myself if I understand the thing correctly. Feels weird, but better ask (dumb - for my stage of development) question and be safe. Googling didn't help. It explains everything except for this specific thing.

It's about P-channel MOSFET as a load switch.

In the picture there is a regular characteristic curve for a P-Channel MOSFET. My question is about DRAIN-SOURCE voltage. The thing is, when the MOSFET conducts, drain-source voltage is effectively zero for currents under, say, 2A, due to tiny Rdson and associated voltage drop (Rdson ~ 50mOhm).

As far as I understand, drain-source voltage means "while MOSFET doesn't conduct". Because, as I said, when MOSFET is a conducting switch - a 0.050Ohm resistor - Vds is always around 0 anyway, unless it's 10A or something. Is my understanding of this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I understand, drain-source voltage means "while MOSFET doesn't conduct"

No, the drain-source voltage \$V_{DS}\$ applies too all situations, including the situation where the MOSFET conducts.

Maybe you're confused because in these curves:

[image]

\$V_{DS}\$ can be quite large, like 2 Volts or more.

Indeed then the MOSFET isn't **fully conducting**, note how the curve for \$V_{GS}\$= -2.5 V at \$V_{DS}\$ = 2 V results in \$I_D\$ = 5 A meaning the MOSFET's resistance (between drain and source) is about 0.4 ohms. That's much higher than the \$R_{DS,on}\$ we generally would want to have (like the 50 mOhm you mention) when switching things.

The difference here is that \$V_{GS}\$= -2.5, meaning the MOSFET **isn't fully switched on**. To fully switch it on, we need a higher \$V_{GS}\$. See how the current increases a lot as \$V_{GS}\$ is increased to -5 V or -10 V. Then the MOSFET is fully turned on and it will have a low \$R_{DS,on}\$.

\$V_{DS}\$ is always simply the voltage across drain-source, independent of the mode of operation of the MOSFET (conducting or not). The curves show us that we need to apply a large \$V_{GS}\$ in order to keep \$V_{DS}\$ low for large currents. But suppose I only want to switch a small current and/or I don't care that \$R_{DS,on}\$ isn't as low as it could be. Maybe I want to apply a lower \$V_{DS}\$ because my circuit doesn't have 5 V available. Then I can see what voltage drop (\$V_{DS}\$) I get for a certain current.

Comment: I want this MOSFET to switch maximum 2A. My Vgs is -2.5V (or more negative - up to -4.4V). What Rdson will I have in that case (worst case)?

Comment: What you mean "Apply Vds"? I don't apply Vds. I only apply source voltage, not drain voltage, I want to open power line via MOSFET. I want to switch 2.5V-4.4V line with maximum current of 2A. And now your post got me even more lost, even though previsouly all my MOSFET circuits worked as I intended them to work, haha :/ I'm trying to understand what the Rds and voltage drop would be

Comment: The curve only shows the **typical** behavior of the MOSFET, so not worst case. At \$I_D\$ = 2 A the curves are close together so it is not easy to see. Your lowest \$V_{GS}\$ is -2.5 V so use that curve. Note how the curve becomes flat (horizontal) above \$V_{DS}\$ = 1 V, there (\$V_{DS}\$ > 1 V) the MOSFET enters saturation mode and it starts behaving like a current source (of around 5A). At \$V_{DS}\$ = 1 V the \$R_{DS,on}\$ will be around 1V/5 A = 200 mOhm, at 2 A it might be a bit lower than that.

Comment: *What you mean "Apply Vds"? I don't apply Vds.* No but to make the curves, a \$V_{DS}\$ is applied. The curve doesn't care what you do! I don't know what you do but the curves are clear. Also the MOSFET doesn't care if you apply a \$V_{DS}\$ or not, if you make it conduct a current, then a \$V_{DS}\$ will develop across the MOSFET. Just like a resistor.

Comment: I think you have completely misunderstood my question. I know that thing about flat area. Give me a moment to rephrase

Comment: My logic: I have Vgs=-2.5V. I expect Drain Current up to 2A. So I pick -2.5V line, go to the left where 2A drain current is. It looks like I have Vds around 0.2-0.3V around that area, from which I derive Rds I will have. Is my reasoning correct now? (estimating worst case, of course, it's more about general reasoning)

Comment: *My logic: I have Vgs=-2.5V. I expect Drain Current up to 2A* NOPE, you apply Vgs = -2.5 V, that then means that the MOSFET behaves in a certain way=> see the curve where Vgs = -2.5 V. For Vds < 1 the MOSFET will behave similar to a resitor of around 200 mOhm. For Vds > 1 V the MOSFET will behave like a 5 A current source. It is up to **you** to make sure that only 2 A flows, the MOSFET doesn't control that.

Comment: *So I pick -2.5V line, go to the left where 2A drain current is. It looks like I have Vds around 0.2-0.3V around that area, from which I derive Rds I will have* Yes that is correct because that is stil in the curved part on the left. It does not apply to the flat part of the curve.

Comment: That is all I needed to know. Much appreciated!